# Add a precondition before count = length(list) in Terraform

Tags: loops, google-cloud-platform, terraform, conditional-statements, terraform-provider-gcp

I need multiple count conditions in a resource block. I am looping through a list to create resources based on the list but I also need to check if they are created in the correct environment. What I need is something like this :
If the environment variable is test then do a loop on the length of table_maps_local

```
resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "tables_as_map" {
  count = var.environment == "test" ? 1 : 0
  count = length(local.table_maps_local)
```

I know we can not set count twice. Any hints on how to proceed on this would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. If the answer helped, its [acceptance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do that using one `count`:

```
resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "tables_as_map" {
  count = var.environment == "test" ? length(local.table_maps_local) : 0
```